# Firebase Security Rules Nesting

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I am creating an reddit-type app. I have an array of stories, and each story has a title, description, and a voteCount. I want to have separate .write rules for the voteCount, so I structured my rules like this -

```
"stories": {
  "$story_id": {

    "title": { ".write": "auth !== null" },
    "description" { ".write": "auth !== null" },
    "voteCount": { ".write": "newData.val() === data.val() + 1" },

  }
}
```

This works for existing stories.However, this no longer allows me to add a new story, unless I add the .write rule directly to the $story_id node. And of course this stops me from having the special .write rule for the voteCount node.

Any ideas on why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

So users have `.write` access on a higher level, but they can only write data that follow specific rules?

You'll want to put that in a `.validation` rule, instead of a `.write` rule.

A simple way to remember this is that `.write` rules determine *who* can write data, while `.validate` rules determine *what* data can be written.

Comment: Thanks. I actually also want to restrict who can write to the voteCount node as well. I just used a simplified version here. The voteCount security node actually looks like this -                                                         `"voteCount": {
              ".write": "auth !== null
                         && newData.val() === data.val() + 1
                         && auth.uid !== root.child('stories').child($story_id).child('user').child('id').val()"
            }`

Comment: Yup, I'd expect an `auth` check in the `.write`. The first step of a solution will be to separate data validation out into a `.validate` rule. And it looks like the last `!==` in there should actually be a `===`.

Comment: Frank has implied this already, but to directly state it:  The reason your current example fails is that there is no .write rule allowing write access at the $story_id level. Being able to access all the children still doesn't allow write to the parent path. So auth != null belongs at the $story_id level, and the rest of the rules (which should, as mentioned, definitely be `.validate`), belong at the child levels.